# Email attribute downcased when accessed via binding.pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, binding.pry

I have a method adjusts an auto-generated email for a user as part of a `before_validation` callback:

```
 def update_device_email
    binding.pry
    self.email = username.gsub(/\s/, '_') + FAKE_EMAIL_SUFFIX
    self.email_confirmation = email
  end
```

For some reason though when I hit the `binding.pry` call, it shows me a downcased version of the email, which then returns to normal after I call `gsub`:

[image]

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1):

You should be checking what the `username` returns prior to the changes being made to `self.email`

Comment: It could be worth to check :)